# SQL one-to-one relationships vs flattening

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using a standard SQL database and I'm trying to figure out whether or not to flatten a table or make it more "object-oriented".  To me, smaller tables are easier to read but it would require joining tables and having one-to-one relationships.  Is this generally a good way of doing things or is it frowned on in the SQL world?

I have a table which has the following attributes:

```
MYTABLE
- ID
- NAME
- LABEL
- CREATED_TS
- MODIFIED_TS
- CREATED_USER
- MODIFIED_USER
```

To me, the created/modified fields would be their own object.  There are actually a few more fields as well so it's not really just this small.  I would think that creating another table called "MYTABLE_MODINFO" or something like that which would have the CREATED and MODIFIED fields and they would be joined when data from them was needed.  These tables aren't high access tables, they wouldn't have tons of queries per minute or even hundreds of rows in them, so I don't think efficiency would be much of an issue.

So mainly what I'm wondering is would this be a generally accepted design or should you generally keep your table structures flat?

Comment: Modification info is not a different "object" - it's inherently part of the main record. Why do you want to split them out?

Comment: Although, Because of the way that the `Created_...` rows would be repeated throughout, you might consider just having the update rows - the creator is the first modifier (performance tradeoffs, though).  Also, don't use data-type suffixes in column names - you can potentially shoot yourself in the foot with that.  Use something like `createdAt`, `createdBy`, `modifiedAt`, `modifiedBy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create audit information in the same table. The reason is that this data is part of the row and is a one to one relationship, so there is no point in branching it apart.

If you want to store the audit info (audit tracking/history), then you can create another table, however in most cases I have seen this built by "duplicating" data and creating a surrogate key and mappings back to the original row. The reason I list duplicating in quotes is because auditing inherently requires duplication of the old data...if it is linked and changeable after being written, then it is not really an audit.

Just my two cents. If it does not make sense, then I can provide some examples. But, the gist is that each row will only ever have one current piece of modification information, so why break it out if it will never have more than one?

Answer (score 1):

avoid a database 'one to one', you'll lose performance, scalability, independence. can you imagine what happen if you want to store 2 pictures per ID? will you create another field or will you repeat the row??... it's easier to create relationship to have more freedom when you want to upgrade, please review this tutorials.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Onzm-PxSjtE

http://folkworm.ceri.memphis.edu/ew/SCHEMA_DOC/comparison/erd.htm

http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/provides/dbmodeling.jsp

Beside that you should normalize the DB to be sure that everything is in the best shape possible.  Remember that the most important is to take what you need and adapt it.

http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzeuBwHkKxw

Comment: How about when the number of columns gets to be 15+ and there are definite groupings with things like positioning, say "X, Y, width height".  Does it make sense to move these out even though they will definitely still be a one-to-one relationship?  To me it gets to be annoying when a table gets to be so large, especially when you are trying to view the data in a grid.

Comment: the number of column is "not important" (even if you have 4096 columns per table), the important thing is a DB relational, with the proper index, PK, and FK, if you have to create 15 tables no problem with that just be sure to create the right structure

Answer (score 1):

RDBMS design aren't the same with object-oriented approach in my view. the example you mentioned aren't different objects domain but data inheritance of your record. Since there would not be any overhead of tons of queries/execution of the table so you should keep them in the same table for auditing purpose and also easier to work with at normalize data.